# Making a method flexible enough to "know" which field it's applied to?

Tags: ruby, methods

In a model we have these flags: `:hidden`, `:phone` and `:email`.

I'd LIKE to write a method called `public_view` that returns either "HIDDEN" or the value of whatever field it's applied to, without having to pass in the DNC flag.

So, `@user.email.public_view` returns the :email, or "HIDDEN", based on `@user.hidden`, and `@user.phone.public_view` returns :phone, or "HIDDEN", based on `@user.hidden`.

Something like:

```
def public_view
  self.SOMETHING.hidden ? "HIDDEN" : self.SOMETHINGELSE
end
```

I suspect there is some very nice class/Ruby way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want a dynamic method to handle the public_view aspect of your fields.

The api for it would not be `@user.email.public_view` since that would require `public_view` to be a method on the `email` field's class. Rather, something like this:

```
@user.public_view_email # returns either the value of the #email method
                        # or "HIDDEN", depending on the #hidden attribute

@user.public_view_phone 
# more generally, handle ALL fields in the form: @user.public_view_<field name>
```

**How to do it**
Use the `method_missing` method to handle the methods. This is the same technique used for the Active Record find_by_foo dynamic methods. A [blog post](http://priodev.blogspot.com/2010/03/methodmissing-and-respondto-doing-it.html) on this.

An example that is NOT tested:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def method_missing(method, *args)
    if method.to_s =~ /^public_view_(.*)$/
      hidden ? "HIDDEN" : send $1
    else
      super
    end
  end

  # also handle responds_to?
  def respond_to?(method, include_private = false)
    if method.to_s =~ /^public_view_(.*)$/
      true
    else
      super
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: great answer thanks... i have no idea why when I clicked ot accept it stackoverflow ignores the click.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like the ? operator, you can factor that out into a method of course.  However, I'm not certain you will gain much in terms of code simplification beyond that using any special gems or other solutions.

This is one case where I'd use the direct, readable, and minimalistic approach.